Error in Fork Testing
I ran the test:
forge test --fork-url $SEPOLIA_RPC_URL 

and this error was returned:
error: a value is required for '--fork-url <URL>' but none was supplied. 

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

// 1. Deploy mocks when we are on a local anvil chain
// 2. Keep track of contract address across different chains
// Sepolia ETH/USD
// Mainnet ETH/USD

pragma solidity ^0.8.18;

import {Script} from "forge-std/Script.sol";
import {MockV3Aggregator} from "../test/mocks/MockV3Aggregator.sol";

contract HelperConfig is Script {
    // If we are on a local anvil, we deploy mocks
    // Otherwise, grab the existing address from the live network

    NetworkConfig public activeNetworkConfig;

    uint8 public constant DECIMALS = 8;
    int256 public constant INITIAL_PRICE = 2000e8;

    struct NetworkConfig {
        address priceFeed;
    }

    constructor() {
        if (block.chainid == 11155111) {
            activeNetworkConfig = getSepoliaEthConfig();
        } else {
            activeNetworkConfig = getOrCreateAnvilEthConfig();
        }
    }

    function getSepoliaEthConfig() public pure returns (NetworkConfig memory) {
        NetworkConfig memory sepoliaConfig = NetworkConfig({
            priceFeed: 0x694AA1769357215DE4FAC081bf1f309aDC325306
        });
        return sepoliaConfig;
    }

    function getOrCreateAnvilEthConfig() public returns (NetworkConfig memory) {
        if (activeNetworkConfig.priceFeed != address(0)) {
            return activeNetworkConfig;
        }
        vm.startBroadcast();
        MockV3Aggregator mockPriceFeed = new MockV3Aggregator(
            DECIMALS,
            INITIAL_PRICE
        );
        vm.stopBroadcast();

        NetworkConfig memory anvilConfig = NetworkConfig({
            priceFeed: address(mockPriceFeed)
        });
        return anvilConfig;
    }
}

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import {AggregatorV3Interface} from "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

/**
 * @title MockV3Aggregator
 * @notice Based on the FluxAggregator contract
 * @notice Use this contract when you need to test
 * other contract's ability to read data from an
 * aggregator contract, but how the aggregator got
 * its answer is unimportant
 */
contract MockV3Aggregator is AggregatorV3Interface {
    uint256 public constant version = 4;

    uint8 public decimals;
    int256 public latestAnswer;
    uint256 public latestTimestamp;
    uint256 public latestRound;

    mapping(uint256 => int256) public getAnswer;
    mapping(uint256 => uint256) public getTimestamp;
    mapping(uint256 => uint256) private getStartedAt;

    constructor(uint8 _decimals, int256 _initialAnswer) {
        decimals = _decimals;
        updateAnswer(_initialAnswer);
    }

    function updateAnswer(int256 _answer) public {
        latestAnswer = _answer;
        latestTimestamp = block.timestamp;
        latestRound++;
        getAnswer[latestRound] = _answer;
        getTimestamp[latestRound] = block.timestamp;
        getStartedAt[latestRound] = block.timestamp;
    }

    function updateRoundData(
        uint80 _roundId,
        int256 _answer,
        uint256 _timestamp,
        uint256 _startedAt
    ) public {
        latestRound = _roundId;
        latestAnswer = _answer;
        latestTimestamp = _timestamp;
        getAnswer[latestRound] = _answer;
        getTimestamp[latestRound] = _timestamp;
        getStartedAt[latestRound] = _startedAt;
    }

    function getRoundData(
        uint80 _roundId
    )
        external
        view
        returns (
            uint80 roundId,
            int256 answer,
            uint256 startedAt,
            uint256 updatedAt,
            uint80 answeredInRound
        )
    {
        return (
            _roundId,
            getAnswer[_roundId],
            getStartedAt[_roundId],
            getTimestamp[_roundId],
            _roundId
        );
    }

    function latestRoundData()
        external
        view
        returns (
            uint80 roundId,
            int256 answer,
            uint256 startedAt,
            uint256 updatedAt,
            uint80 answeredInRound
        )
    {
        return (
            uint80(latestRound),
            getAnswer[latestRound],
            getStartedAt[latestRound],
            getTimestamp[latestRound],
            uint80(latestRound)
        );
    }

    function description() external pure returns (string memory) {
        return "v0.6/test/mock/MockV3Aggregator.sol";
    }
}

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.18;

import {Test, console} from "forge-std/Test.sol";
import {FundMe} from "../src/FundMe.sol";
import {DeployFundMe} from "../script/DeployFundMe.s.sol";

contract FundMeTest is Test {
    FundMe fundMe;

    function setUp() external {
        //        fundMe = new FundMe(0x694AA1769357215DE4FAC081bf1f309aDC325306);
        DeployFundMe deployFundMe = new DeployFundMe();
        fundMe = deployFundMe.run();
    }

    function testMinimumDollarisFive() public view {
        assertEq(fundMe.MINIMUM_USD(), 5e18);
    }

    function testOwnerIsMsgSender() public view {
        console.log(fundMe.i_owner());
        console.log(msg.sender);
        assertEq(fundMe.i_owner(), msg.sender);
    }

    function testPriceFeedVersionIsAccurate() public view {
        uint256 version = fundMe.getVersion();
        assertEq(version, 4);
    }
}



Make sure that you've defined the environment variable named as SEPOLIA_RPC_URL in your .env file.

Then, run this command to load environment variables from .env file into the current shell session:
source .env


Now, you can run the test on forked network, using:
forge test --fork-url $SEPOLIA_RPC_URL



